# How to add cancellation support to async UI tasks?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, task-parallel-library, winrt-xaml, async-await

I am looking into adding cancellation support to awaitable extension methods in the [AsyncUI](http://asyncui.codeplex.com/) and [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) libraries. It seems like the base Task class does not have a built-in Cancel() method or event and relies on cancellation tokens that my tasks would need to check for periodically. I think does not make sense in my UI scenarios, since my tasks are generated using the TaskCompletionSource and I would like to cancel the tasks on the UI thread in response to events instead of running a loop on a thread pool thread and checking for a token.

My tasks currently complete when a UI event happens - like a Storyboard completing or a button being clicked, so if I want to support cancellation - I need to respond to a cancellation request by unsubscribing from events and doing other cleanup like stopping an animation .

I am thinking of creating some sort of CancellableUITask base class instead of using the TaskCompletionSource, so I could expose a Cancel() method that the consumer of my task could call (e.g. to stop an awaited animation in response to a button click) and something like a virtual OnCancellationRequested() method that my storyboard awaiter task could override to perform cleanup.

Does it make sense? What would be the best way to accomplish what I am describing here?

Comment: I don't understand. How would your solution be any better than using `CancellationToken` (possibly with [`Register()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register) to avoid polling) and [`TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449188)?

Comment: Well, I did not know of the Register method, that is why I am asking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tasks would not need to check periodically for cancellation - that is just the most common way of doing things. If your tasks are event-driven, then you can register a handler against the `CancellationToken` that will be called when it is cancelled. See [`CancellationToken.Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321953.aspx).

So your code might look something like this:

```
public Task DoSomethingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();

    if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
    {
        // register for notification of cancellation
        cancellationToken.Register(...);
    }

    // set up other handlers and what-not

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: I'll see if that works. I'm not too happy about needing to add another overload to all my methods making them seem a bit more complicated. I was thinking subclassing Task could work better. Do you think it might be a bad idea for any reason?

Comment: @Filip: what extra overload is required? Note that I used an optional parameter for the `CancellationToken`, so no extra overload is necessary.

Comment: I thought an optional parameter generates a new overload in the back? Anyways, I just looked at my methods and they are not too complicated parameter-wise, so another one for CancellationToken should be OK.

Comment: @FilipSkakun No, optional parameter does not generate a new overload, instead it always just calls original method with your default value if not provided. It may seem the same, but a bit different in case of calling a method between assemblies. Read more about default values.